# Getting error in Range Definition with Last Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure sure what I am doing wrong in trying to copy a range from one worksheet to another. Trying to copy from "LeadSheet" to "HistoricalDataSheet". Leadsheet Data will always start with Row 5 and copy the full rows until the last row. Then paste into the row after the last row on "HistoricalDataSHeet" and format the first column for date:

```
Sub CopyToHistorical()

Dim a, LR As Integer

With Worksheets("LeadSheet")
LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Worksheets("LeadSheet")
**.Range("5:LR").Copy**
'this is where I am getting there error'

End With


With Worksheets("HistoricalLeadData")
a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Sheets("HistoricalLeadData").Range("A" & a + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

With Sheets("HistoricalLeadData")
.Range(.Range("A" & a + 1), .Range("A" & a + 1).End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: `.Range("5:" & LR).Copy`

Comment: Lord I feel stupid. Thanks! :)